# Hot sauce preserved ingredents

Tags: storage-lifetime

I am  in the process of launching a hot sauce business. . but I would life to know what ingredients  to add in it so that it have a longer shelf life ..

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. Vinegar and capsicum would make it inhospitable for microbes. And consumers don't want products with preservatives anyway.

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure it is the right thing to start a business now without knowing the basics?

Comment: @aris vinegar is a good preservative, but also an assumption on your part, i.e. it's common in hot sauce but not universal, and the proportion isn't always enough. Capsicum on the other hand has no preservative value

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/does-spicy-food-have-antibacterial-traits